# Описание массива из комплексных чисел

Tags: java

Пишу программу для решения системы уравнений с комплексными числами методом Гаусса. Сам алгоритм я реализовал. Встал вопрос с описанием комплексных чисел. Код программы прилагается.

```
public class Gauss{
static int i,j,n,k,h,c;
double m,s;
static boolean f;
static double[][] buf;
static double[][] matrix;
static double[] b,x;
static void Prisvoi(int n){
    buf = new double[n][n];
    matrix = new double[n][n];
    b = new double[n];  
    x = new double[n];
    k=0; c=0; f=false;
}
void MetodGaussa(){
    //Прямой ход
    for(h=1;h<n;h++){
        if(matrix[k][k]==0){
            for(i=1+k;i<n;i++){if(matrix[i][k]!=0){c=i;}
            if(c!=0){
                for(j=0;j<n;j++){
                    buf[0][j]=matrix[k][j];
                    matrix[k][j]=matrix[c][j];
                    matrix[c][j]=buf[0][j];
                    if(j==n-1){
                        buf[0][j+1]=b[k];
                        b[k]=b[c];
                        b[k]=buf[0][j+1];
                    }
                }
                //buf=nill;
                for(i=1+k;i<n;i++){
                    for(j=0+k;j<n;j++){
                        if(j==0+k){m=matrix[i][k]/matrix[k][k];}
                        matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j]-matrix[k][j]*m;
                        if(j==n-1){b[i]=b[i]-b[k]*m;}
                    }
                    f=true;
                }
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("Нет максимума в системе уравнений");
                f=false;
            }
            }
        }
        else{
            for(i=1+k;i<n;i++){
                for(j=0+k;j<n;j++){
                    if(j==0+k){m=matrix[i][k]/matrix[k][k];}
                    matrix[i][j]=matrix[i][j]-matrix[k][j]*m;
                    if(j==n-1){b[i]=b[i]-b[k]*m;}
                }
            } 
            f=true;
        }
    }
    //Расчёт корней
    if(f==true){
        if(matrix[n-1][n-1]==0){
            x[n-1]=b[n-1]/matrix[n-1][n-1];
            for(i=n-2;i>-1;i--){
                s= 0;
                for(j=i+1;j<n;j++){s=s-matrix[i][j]*x[j];}
                x[i]=(b[i]+s)/matrix[i][i];
            }
        }
        else{
            if(b[n-1]==0){System.out.println("Система уравнений не имеет решения");}
            else System.out.println("Система уравений имеет бесконечное множество решений");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А в чём проблема? Напишите свой класс `Complex`, и дело с концом. Правда, Java не позволяет перегружать операторы, так что вместо + у вас будет `.add()` и т. д.

Ну или если лень, возьмите любую из свободных реализаций. Список [тут](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complex_data_type).

Comment: Спасибо уже разобрался с вопросом

Answer (score 1):

Прекрасная реализация комплексных чисел есть в библиотеке Apache Math ([javadoc](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/complex.html), [учебник](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/apidocs/org/apache/commons/math3/complex/Complex.html), [конфиг для maven и других систем](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.commons/commons-math3), [скачать исходники](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/download_math.cgi)).

Кстати, там есть и реализации алгоритмов решения СЛАУ, причём несколько. Рекомендую ознакомиться хотя бы потому, что код, на мой взгляд, очень качественный.

Приводить код здесь не буду, т.к. кода много. Думаю, в обозримом будущем Apache никуда не денется.